# Java - Android - Functions

Tags: java

How do you call this function :
`'Z'.toString();`
And why are they not like to `toString('Z');`
And can you do this kind of methods yourself?

Comment: It's "Z".toString(), not 'Z'.toString(). Because "Z" is a [String, you can call String methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `'Z'.toString()` because `'Z'` is of the primitive `char` type and therefore not an object. To convert a `char` to a `String`, use the method [`Character.toString(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(char)). For example:

```
String s = Character.toString('Z');
// Or
char chval = 'Z';
String s = Character.toString(chval);
```

As for your other question:

> And can you do this kind of methods yourself?

Answer: Yes, but it is not necessary because `Character.toString()` is already implemented for use.